# What to do with the message " 'variable' is declared but its value is never read."

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a function that takes 2 integers and returns the sum of every number between(and including) them.

I also want it to work when the first integer `x` is larger than the second `y`, for that I've written this:

```
if (x > y) {
  let temp = x;
  x = y;
  y = x;
}
```

However, I get this message on Visual Studio Code:

> 'temp' is declared but its value is never read.

What is the problem?

Also, this is the complete script:

```
const sumAll = function( x , y ) {

    if (x !== Math.abs(x) || y !== Math.abs(y)) return ("ERROR");
    if (typeof x !== "number" || typeof y !== "number") return ("ERROR");
    if (x > y) {
        let temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = x;
    }
    let finalSum = 0;
    for (i = x; i <= y; i++){
        finalSum += i;
    }
   return finalSum; 
}
```

Comment: It means you create the variable but never use it. You can probably suppress the warning but it would be better to just not create the variable.

Comment: Do you not want to do `y = temp`?

Comment: What's the point of declaring a variable and never use it? There's not, hence the warning.

Comment: `x = y` will make `x` the value of `y`, so they will be the same. It then makes no sense to assign `y = x` since they are equal already. You'll need to assign `temp` to `y` so the old original value is set to `y`.

Comment: If you want to switch 2 integers, there's also this possibility but that's really if you don't want a temporary variable: x=x+y;y=x-y;x=x-y;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are just setting the value and not using the variable, that's why it is showing that message.

You might wanted to have the below code

```
if (x > y) {
        let temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
```

Comment: My pleasure... Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temporary variable to swap variables values, just use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables):

```js
let x = 10;
let y = 7;

if (x > y) {
  [x, y] = [y, x];
}

console.log('x =', x);
console.log('y =', y);
```